# How to Instantly Scroll to Position?

Tags: javascript, scroll, smooth-scrolling

How to instantly scroll window to some position with JavaScript, when smooth-scrolling is enabled?

```css
:root {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Is there a way to ignore this CSS rule? Something like this:

```js
window.scrollBy({ top: 0, behavior: 'instantly' });
```

Comment: The only valid values for [`behavior`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScrollToOptions/behavior) are `smooth` and `auto`. There is no `instantly`.

Comment: @Turnip oh, really? Are you kidding, don't you? I know that there is no `behavior: instantly`, I wrote it as an example.

Comment: @Turnip ok, ok. I understand I can't do this with `scrollBy`, I'm looking for some other way to realise instant scroll. That was just an example of what I want to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could set the `scroll-behavior` before calling `.scrollBy()` and then reset it after.

```js
var root = document.querySelector(':root');
var btnInstantScroll = document.querySelector('#btnInstantScroll');
var btnDefaultScroll = document.querySelector('#btnDefaultScroll');

btnInstantScroll.addEventListener('click', function() {

  // Change scroll behavior
  root.setAttribute("style", "scroll-behavior: auto;");

  // Timeout ensures styles are applied before scrolling
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0, -2000);
    
    // Reset to CSS defaults.
    root.removeAttribute("style");
  }, 0)

})

btnDefaultScroll.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.scrollBy(0, -2000);
})
```

```css
:root {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.scrollable {
  height: 2000px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(#e66465, #e66465 20px, #9198e5 20px, #9198e5 25px);
}

.controls {
  padding: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">

</div>

<div class="controls">
  <button type="button" id="btnInstantScroll">
    Instant scroll
  </button>

  <button type="button" id="btnDefaultScroll">
    Scroll using doc settings
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought there is a more straightforward way exist to do this without resetting `scroll-behavior`. Anyway, it works, so thank you.

Answer (score 15):

There you go :

```js
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'instant',
});
```

Comment: Seems 'instant' doesn't exist anymore, only "auto", which is the default and supposed to be the same as "instant" (but I'm not sure it works), or "smooth" which is animated smoothly.

Comment: "instant" value appears to be still valid according to [MDN docs](https://prnt.sc/uOlOMhao-Bwi)

Answer (score 6):

`scroll-behavior: auto;`  DOES NOT work. and  `scroll-behavior: instant;`  no longer exists

This is the only thing that worked for me:

```css
html {

  scroll-behavior: auto !important;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried scroll option `behavior: auto`?

```
var scrollOptions = {
    left: leftValue,
    top: topValue,
    behavior: 'auto'
}

window.scrollBy(scrollOptions);
```